# don't keep activities in Android ICS

Tags: android

My code to view system thumbnail with database.
It works in Android 2.x.
But while press back button, it does not work in Android 4.0.3.
But if I select the "don't keep activities" option in "Developer options".
It works.
If I did not change system setting, and modify by code.
How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [the `android:launchMode` property](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) of the `activity` element in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: use the default value:"standard", please don't use "singleXXX"